# Fetch data using an id from an api but display an alternative text to address bar e.g. content_title in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm using an api that only allows fetching data using an *id* **BUT NOT** *title* as follows `http://0.0.0.0:5000/blog/13b03a39-bc04-4604-baf6-059658f9f5e8` . The endpoint returns a JSON object which I want to render to browser using Next Js. However I want to have a clean url architecture that contains title *as follows*:

[image: clean]

*instead of a url containing the id as follows:*

[image: dirty]

Here's how I'm passing `props` to `Link` :

```
<Link
    href={`/post/${post.blog_title}`}
    as={`/post/${post.blog_title}`}>
    
    <a className='blog__card--link'>
        <h4 className='blog__card--title'>{post.blog_title}</h4>
    </a>
</Link>
```

and here's is my `[id].js` file:

```
import { getBlog } from '../../api/index';

const Article = ({ blog }) => {
    const router = useRouter();

    return (
        <div class='article'>
            <div class='article__main'>
                {/* {console.log(router)} */}
                <ArticleView />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

Article.getInitialProps = async (router) => {
    const res = await getBlog(`${router.query.id}`);
    const json = await res.json();
    console.log(json);

    return { blog: json };
};

export default Article;
```

Trying to access `${router.query.id}` in `getInitialProps` it returns the title which I understand is what I'm passing through `as prop in Link`.

Is it possible to achieve a clean url structure but also use `id` in `getInitialProps`? and how can I achieve it using dynamic links in Next.js ?

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**

*-> The only good alternative is to use slugs in the API because imagine someone follows a link to your post from another site or perhaps enter the URL in the browser address bar? How would you know what to query for from the backend? Therefore this question comes from a place of impracticality , choosing to retain it on the site for the sake of others in the future.*

Comment: How are you dealing when a user enter directly the URL in the browser?

Comment: I settled to using slug since what I was trying to achieve is actually not practical, however I decided to keep the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was trying to achieve in this question is not practical therefore I settled to having unique slugs in the back-end that can be used to fetch the specific data.

Take a scenario where a link to your article/post is shared somewhere else, then the only way to get data to that post/article is using a slug.

Answer (score 1):

you need to import Next/Router

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
```

change your getInitialProps function to

```
Article.getInitialProps = async (router) => {
    //get id query parameter
    const res = await getBlog(`${router.query.id}`);
    const json = await res.json();
    console.log(json);

    return { blog: json };
};
```

this should work for you

Comment: just came back to this question to upvote answers, since I realized the reason I had this issue was I was not passing any parameters to `getInitialProps` . However this did not really solve my problem, I resulted to fetching using `title` instead of `id`

Answer (score 1):

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps#context-object

```
 Article.getInitialProps = async function(context) => {
    const res = await getBlog(`${context.query.id}`);
    const json = await res.json();
    console.log(json);

    return { blog: json };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

solution 1
however this base on your endpoint my suggest is change endpoint to receive slug so you can manage your slug

solution 2
not best practice but you can get clean url and get data by id Using Redux

solution 3
[using next-routes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-routes) using next-routes and pass id as params

```
<Link route='blog' params={{id: data.id}}>
<a>Hello world</a>
</Link>
```